# is Windows phone's Launcher similar functionality available on iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing an application using Xamarin Forms, targeting iOS, Android and Windows Phone.

Using `Dependency Service`, I implemented to open/preview file that can be an audio, video or text document.

On Android, I used `Intent` with `Android.Content.Intent.ActionView`.
On Windows Phone, I used Launchers.

Is there any similar simple way on iOS to view a file?